# Weird behavior of Lucene query parser 5.1.0

Tags: solr, lucene, query-parser

I am using Lucene Query Parser 5.1.0

These filter queries do not work:

```
* AND {!tag=guid}guid:(*)
* && {!tag=guid}guid:(*)
* {!tag=guid}guid:(*)
```

it throws

`org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'guid:(*': Encountered \"<EOF>\" at line 1, column 7.\nWas expecting one of:\n    <AND> ...\n    <OR> ...\n    <NOT> ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <BAREOPER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \")\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    \"^\" ...\n    <QUOTED> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\n    <WILDTERM> ...\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    <LPARAMS> ...\n    <NUMBER> ...\n`

And these filter queries do work:

```
* AND {!tag=guid}guid:*
* AND guid:(*)
* AND guid:*
* && {!tag=guid}guid:*
* && guid:(*)
* && guid:*
* {!tag=guid}guid:*
* guid:(*)
* guid:*
{!tag=guid}guid:(*)
{!tag=guid}guid:*
guid:(*)
guid:*
```

Why the first three do not work? Is it a bug in the query parser?

EDIT:
I have found weird behavior also with spaces:

This does work:

```
* AND {!tag=guid}guid:"a"
```

This does not work:

```
* AND {!tag=guid}guid:"a "
```

Comment: In the first query, you have 4 open and only 3 closed brackets.  Possibly this causes an error.

Comment: Sorry, of course it does not work even with correct braces

Comment: Hint: may relate to https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/queryparser/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.jj

Answer (score 0):

Tags in FilterQueries are just special kind of LocalParameter used as reference point for faceting in SOLR.

Note that LocalParameters are **SOLR specific** and are not parsed in any meaningfull way with LuceneQueryParser.

If you are interested in general LocalParameter syntax, you can check:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Local+Parameters+in+Queries

According to that document

> Local parameters are arguments in a Solr request that are **specific** to 
>   a query parameter.

and

> **Basic Syntax of Local Parameters:**
>
> To specify a local parameter, insert the following **before the argument**
>   to be modified:
>
> - Begin with {!
> - Insert any number of key=value pairs separated by white space
> - End with } and immediately follow with the query argument
>
> You may specify only one local parameters prefix per argument.

You shouldn't therefore prefix Local Parameters with any parts of query as you do. If you really need to use multiple LocalParameters consider splitting big FilterQuery to multiple smaller ones using CNF

---

Additional usefull resource:
https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/QParser.java